# How to debug: Parsoid "stopping" after getting wiki-metadata

Tags: mediawiki, parsoid

In a plain media-wiki 1.30.0 (shared hosting) + parsoid 0.8 (local hosting) setup, parsoid fails to convert wikitext to html; it "stops" after having requested some metadata from the wiki.

Making a request for the conversion of the main page ("Hauptseite") via curl (that is `curl localhost:8142/eirene-wiki/v3/page/html/Hauptseite`) results in an empty reply. `httpry` tells me that parsoid queried the wiki once, to get some metadata - I would expect a second request to get the content of the page.

```
> sudo httpry
2017-12-12 14:26:17 192.168.178.20  80.67.17.142    >   GET eirene-wiki.org /mediawiki-1.30.0/api.php?format=json&action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces%7Cnamespacealiases%7Cmagicwords%7Cfunctionhooks%7Cextensiontags%7Cgeneral%7Cinterwikimap%7Clanguages%7Clanguagevariants%7Cprotocols%7Cspecialpagealiases%7Cdefaultoptions%7Cvariables&rawcontinue=1  HTTP/1.1    --
2017-12-12 14:26:18 80.67.17.142    192.168.178.20  <   -   -   -HTTP/1.1   200 OK
```

Unfortunately, the logfile of parsoid does not show anything but statistics about the memory usage, although I set the log level to `trace`.

What can I do to investigate this issue further?

Comment: That URL sounds like the request is going through RESTBase so maybe look at `restbase.log` and/or test Parsoid directly (`localhost:8000/html/Hauptseite` I think).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to check for RESTBase - but its not involved, just plain Parsoid.